# is it possible to list all public APIs of a class using CLANG

Tags: python, c++, clang

I want to create a Class-wise list of all

- Classes
- Public APIs

Can this be done using Clang?

Note: trying to do this using Python

Comment: What do you mean by `public APIs`?

Comment: public member functions of a class.

Comment: Then, technically, the exact answer is "Yes". I suggest you to expand your question - to get the better answers.